# The ajax code is not working in eclipse with jsf and maven

Tags: jsf-2, maven-2

This is my Bean class and I am using xhtml with use of maven all the required jar in pom.xml

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSayWelcome(){
    //check if null?
    if("".equals(name) || name ==null){
        return "";
    }else{
        return "Ajax message : Welcome " + name;
    }
}
```

}

and this is my helloAjax.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:body>
    <h3>JSF 2.0 + Ajax Hello World Example</h3>

    <h:form>

        <h:inputText id="name" value="#{helloBean.name}"></h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me">
             <f:ajax execute="name" render="output" />
        </h:commandButton>

        <h2><h:outputText id="output" value="#{helloBean.sayWelcome}" /></h2>

    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

But after running this page I am getting only title in output and I am using jsf-api and jsf-imple in pom.xml.

Plz guide me.